# Select a range of integers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a 'range' of integers (in this case destination ports) that occur:

For example: 33848-33254.

I want to select 'all' of these without having to do one at a time. is there a range operator? Or should I just use 'between'?

Comment: between is just fine, nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `BETWEEN` or greater than/less than operators:

```
select *
from yourtable
where col1 >= 33254 and col1 <= 33848;
```

or

```
select *
from yourtable
where col1 between 33254 and 33848;
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/0c665/3)

Comment: I've been told that it's better to use the lt/gt ops, because "performance". Is that a lie?

Comment: @jcolebrand I am not sure, we probably need feedback from some of the other experts on the site.

Comment: @jcolebrand: yes that's a lie. `between` will work just as fast as using `<` and `>`. And that's true for almost all DBMS, not only Postgres

Comment: A question please, Could it works with 'between' if columns where store the number is type text. Thanks!

Comment: @FernandoPie - if they're valid numbers, then just `SELECT '3.4'::NUMERIC;` - see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sp4Nij0j).

Comment: @FernandoPie it depends on what you're trying to do. You can also do the reverse of what @Vérace said: if the columns are text, cast the parameters to text. It will do a string comparison, but at least that way you'd be casting one or two input values instead of all that column's values in the table. You may risk data loss when converting, such as treating US ZIP codes as numbers will cause some to lose their leading zeroes. Comparing text `00010` and number `10` would match if both are number types, but not if the number `10` was cast to text. `between` works with text (think sorting).

Answer (score 1):

[`BETWEEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparison.html) is your friend, as in

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name
BETWEEN value1 AND value2
```